# Failed use a method after added new method in controller ASP API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

At first I have a method in controller api to add a record to database. below my method :

```
   [HttpPost]
    public Response<UserView> AddUser(UserView user)
    {
        EntityFirstApp.User mappedUser = Mapper.Map <EntityFirstApp.User>(user); 

        var entityUser = this._userService.AddUser(mappedUser);

        UserView userView = Mapper.Map<UserView>(entityUser);

        //// build response
        var response = new Response<UserView> { Model = userView };

        response.Messages.Add(new Message
        {
            MessageType = MessageType.Success,
            Value = "Success"
        });

        return response;
    }
```

That method work well before I added another method to delete record. below my other method

```
  [HttpPost]
    public Response<UserView> DeleteUser(Int64 Id)
    {
        var entityUser = this._userService.GetUserById(Id);
        this._userService.DeleteUser(Id);

       UserView userView = Mapper.Map<UserView>(entityUser);

      //// build response
        var response = new Response<UserView> { Model = userView };

       response.Messages.Add(new Message
       {
           MessageType = MessageType.Success,
           Value = "Success"
       });

        return response;
    }
```

after I added **DeleteUser** method, I can't use AddUser method anymore. I got **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)** in browser console. In front I use angularjs to consume that method. below my code in front.

```
    userModule.service('userService', userService);

userService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'commonEnum'];

function userService($http, $q, commonEnum) {

    var userService = {
        getAllUser: getAllUser,
        addUser: addUser,
        deleteUser : deleteUser
    }

    return userService;

    function getAllUser() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: commonEnum.ajaxMethod.get,
            url: commonEnum.baseApiUrl.base + commonEnum.webApiUrl.getAllUser,
        })
            .success(onSuccess)
            .error(onError);

        function onSuccess(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }

        function onError() {
            deferred.reject();
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function addUser(user) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: commonEnum.ajaxMethod.post,
            url: commonEnum.baseApiUrl.base + commonEnum.webApiUrl.addUser,
            data: user
        })
            .success(onSuccess)
            .error(onError);

        function onSuccess(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }

        function onError() {
            deferred.reject();
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function deleteUser(userId) {
        var parameters = {
            Id: userId
        }
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: commonEnum.ajaxMethod.post,
            url: commonEnum.baseApiUrl.base + commonEnum.webApiUrl.deleteUser,
            params: parameters
        })
            .success(onSuccess)
            .error(onError);

        function onSuccess(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }

        function onError() {
            deferred.reject();
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

I still can't figured out why. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is "return userService;" causing this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use the `DELETE` HTTP verb for your `DeleteUser` method - it just kind of sounds more ReSTful? Also it would help if you showed the exact response from the server from this 400 Bad Request Status code (that can be seen in the Network tab in your developer console of the browser).

Comment: After I worked around for some time, the problem is about route config for API. default mapper is like ' routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",' so that is way I can not have 2 post method in 1controller class. so changed into ' routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",'.